# Does iOS app developer have access to my iCloud billing info?

Tags: ios, icloud, apple-id, privacy, billing

I see this data in my [iCloud purchase history](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204088). There are my credit card number, my first and last name, my address, and iPhone's name.

1. Which of this are accessible to the developer of the app?
2. Is it possible for developers to track reinstallation of their apps thought this data? How is that conforms with [Uber's case](https://ios.gadgethacks.com/news/uber-tracked-iphone-users-even-after-deleting-app-0177265/)?
   [image]

Comment: Note to closer this is about the AppStore and not software development so is on topic here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the iOS app developers do not have access to your billing info.

When an app is sold through the App Store, the third party developer does not get access to the credit card number, first or last names, your address nor the iPhone's name.

As a consequence of this, the developer cannot track reinstallations through the means of the above mentioned data.